# Pass sass variable to a sass mixin

Tags: sass, stenciljs, scss-mixins

how to pass a sass variable to a sass mixin and work with the value ?

I have defined a variable:
`$flex-direction: var(--flex-direction,row) !default`

And wrote a mixin

```
@mixin flex($direction) {
    @debug "Value of direction arg:>>"+inspect($value: $direction);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: $direction;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    @if $direction ==row {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    @else if $direction ==row-reverse {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    @else if $direction ==column {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    @else if $direction ==column-reverse {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use the mixin as

```
.container {
 @includes flex($flex-direction)
}
```

It is always resolved to `stdin:21 Debug: Value of direction arg:>>var(--control-bar-flex-direction, row)`

how to do it ?

I want the the mixin to work based on the variable value and the variable value to resolve to the actual value rather than the string

Answer (score 0):

CSS Variables cannot be resolved by sass, as they are only resolved, as soon as the CSS runs in the browser. So in sass they will always be treated as a string. You have to switch from a CSS var to a sass var:

```
$flex-direction: row !default;
```

And just to be clear: You can't use a sass mixin in the browser, as it is only available for compiling the css with the sass compiler.

Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement the same ?

Comment: Maybe, if you can explain what exactly you want to achieve. Let me guess: The css variable —flex-direction is from an external source, you have no control over?